# Using a void* to change a char

Tags: c

I'm trying to parse the mac address from a Wi-Fi module, but I have some trouble..
When I call the `wifi_get_mac()`, It works fine when it at the parsing state going to `on_get_mac_result_line` where I get the mac address after the `sscanf`, but when I'm back to the `wifi_get_mac`, mac is just something random..

```
static void* wifi_process_line_data;
static void (*wifi_process_line_func)(void* data, const char* line, int length);

static void on_get_mac_result_line(void* data, const char* line, int length)
{
    if (wifi_state != STATE_IDLE) {
        char mac[length];
        char *p = mac;
        if (sscanf(line, "%17s", mac) == 1) {
            *(char*) data = mac;
        }
    }
}

char* wifi_get_mac(void){
    static char mac[17];
    char *p = mac;
    wifi_process_line_data = p;
    wifi_process_line_func = on_get_mac_result_line;
    if (wifi_perform_s2w_command("AT+NMAC=?\n") && mac[0] != '\0') {
        return '\0';
    }
    return mac;
}
```

I know this works to get the rssi

```
static void on_get_rssi_result_line(void* data, const char* line, int length)
{
    if (wifi_state != STATE_IDLE) {
        int rssi;
        if (sscanf(line, "%d", &rssi) == 1) {
            *(int*)data = rssi;
        }
    }
}

int wifi_get_rssi(void)
{
    int rssi = INT_MAX;
    wifi_process_line_data = &rssi;
    wifi_process_line_func = on_get_rssi_result_line;
    if (wifi_perform_s2w_command("AT+WRSSI=?\n") && rssi != INT_MAX) {
        return rssi;
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}
```

Comment: in `on_get_mac_result_line`, you need to copy the entire `char` array with eg. [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)

Comment: yeah, more like it `strcpy((char*) data ,mac);`

Comment: It may appear to work, but your code remains incorrect, a MAC address string in colon-separated hex-byte format is 17 characters long, so your `mac` buffer needs to be length 18 to accommodate the nul string terminator.

Comment: to be fully transparent: now discussed on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/what-if-i-dont-want-to-answer-but-still-want-to-help

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.  It is also missing important parts - notably the `main()` and at least one `#include` directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char mac[length];` is local to the `on_get_mac_result_line` function. Attempts to access it outside of that function should not be made.

You'll have to copy the entire `char` array into the `data` destination to make the result available to the calling function (`wifi_get_mac`). Eg. by using [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) :

```
strncpy((char*) data, mac, 17);
```

Comment: The cast is not necessary.

Comment: @Clifford : sure, but I still prefer to have it explicit.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
*(char*) data = mac;
```

attempts to assign a `char*` to a `char` - in GCC it yields the following warning:

```
    warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

You should have something similar and should never ignore the warnings.

What you need to do here is copy the string generated in `mac` to the buffer provided by the caller `data` :

```
static void on_get_mac_result_line( void* data, const char* line, int length )
{
    if( wifi_state != STATE_IDLE ) 
    {
        char mac[length] ;

        if( sscanf_s( line, "%17s", mac, length ) == 1 ) 
        {
            strcpy( data, mac) ;
        }
    }
}
```

You should take measures also to ensure that `length` is sufficient to prevent an overrun, for example you could either check that `length` is at least 18, or use `sscanf_s` as I have above.

Note that `p` in your original implementation is unused and serves no purpose.

Comment: I'm under the impression that someone is punishing you because of the meta question. not fair.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : Oh well; I'll live.  ;-)